# Continuous function at [-1,1] not differentiable at infinite points at [-1,1].

Tags: calculus

Is anybody that can answer the following exercise?: "Give a continuous function at [-1,1] not differentiable at infinite points at [-1,1]."

Thank so much!

Comment: This is a fun counterexample for a number of things: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: (Picky remark: There are no infinite points in $[-1,1]$, or in the whole set of real numbers for that matter. But there are infinitely *many*...)

Answer (score 3):

You could at least tell us what you tried, but

$$\left| \, x \,\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \right|$$

Should work

Comment: But this function is not continuous at zero and the function which im asking for should be continuous at [-1,1].

Comment: It most certainly is.